Is there a way to get the Linux CPU scheduling events with time?
I want to calculate the time for a specific process to get scheduled in the CPU after it went to the ready state and how many other processes got scheduled in the mean time. Is there any existing tools for that or do I have to write them by myself?
I have tried modifying the kernel by calling printK() function in the appropriate functions but this have a huge impact on the performace (I think it ran into deadlocks).

Pretty sure you are looking for perf trace; there are many scheduling events exposed via tracepoints you could use. Also take a look at perf sched script which is a higher-level script over these tracepoints info.

@AndreyTurkin, Thank you for your help. I installed perf and tried to use perf trace. but it keeps saying  'perf: 'trace' is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help'.'. Even the help page of 'perf' does not have that. Is it an issue with my 'perf' version? I saw an older tutorial of 'perf' also using perf trace, but there is no 'perf' trace in my version. Any idea about that?

You are right, there is no literal 'perf trace' command in newer perf. However the functionality is still there; you can use e.g. 'perf record' to capture a tracefile of some event(s) what occurs on your system. See also 'perf list "sched:*"' for a list of static scheduler tracepoints you could tap into with perf record or other perf subcommands. You can probably solve your task using them, but you can also set new dynamic tracepoints on any kernel function (what you tried to do with printk just done better). I can't tell you exactly how to use it for you task but perf is the tool you need

You can use Linux sched tracing(most distributions of Linux kernel have this feature):
# enable tracing
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
# enable sched tracing
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/enable
# set the log buffer size
echo 10240 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb
# get the sched log
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace

You can output the sched log to a file, and use this tools to convert it to graphical interface:
https://github.com/google/schedviz
